# ElasticBeanstalk Deployment Failed: WSGI cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am facing Django deployment issues related wsgi configuration and wanted to see if everything is fine from project setup and EBS side i.e. correct WSGI, python version.

**I am following standard project structure:**

```
    [dhango_project]/
    ├── [dhango_project]/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    |
    |── [blog]
    |── [static]/ 
    |   ├── [css]
    |   ├── [Javascript]
    |   └── [Images]
    |
    |── [templates]
    |── manage.py
    └── requirements.txt
```

**dhango_project/.ebextensions/django.config**

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "dhango_project/wsgi.py"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
```

**I am seeing error :**

```
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Apr 30 13:26:27.696673 2021] [:error] [pid 28548] [remote xxxxx] File “/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py”, line 83, in populate
[Fri Apr 30 13:26:27.696676 2021] [:error] [pid 28548] [remote xxxxx] raise RuntimeError(“populate() isn’t reentrant”)
[Fri Apr 30 13:26:27.696688 2021] [:error] [pid 28548] [remote xxxxx] RuntimeError: populate() isn’t reentrant
[Fri Apr 30 13:26:38.189812 2021] [:error] [pid 28548] [remote xxxxx] mod_wsgi (pid=28548): Target WSGI script ‘/opt/python/current/app/dhango_project/wsgi.py’ cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Apr 30 13:26:38.189855 2021] [:error] [pid 28548] [remote xxxxxx] mod_wsgi (pid=28548): Exception occurred processing WSGI script ‘/opt/python/current/app/dhango_project/wsgi.py’.
[Fri Apr 30 13:26:38.189952 2021] [:error] [pid 28548] [remote xxxxxx] Traceback (most recent call last):

[Fri Apr 30 13:26:38.189977 2021] [:error] [pid 28548] [remote xxxxxx] File “/opt/python/current/app/dhango_project/wsgi.py”, line 16, in
[Fri Apr 30 13:26:38.189980 2021] [:error] [pid 28548] [remote xxxxxx] application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by downgrading Django==2.1.7 from Django==3.0.8.

[For More Info](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/500)